# How to change background color of button using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react using bootstrap, initially I am giving same colors to my buttons, now What I am trying to do is on click of button change that button's color and if I click on other button it change the color of that and the first one back to basic (default) color

I have done this using jquery earlier as passing onclick event and toggle the color but here I am new to react so don't know how to do that.

My code

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-brook-en64x?file=/src/App.js)

**What I am looking for** is suppose I have 7 buttons and I click on first one then its color should change , then If I am clicking on next button then first should come to normal and the clicked (second) one should changed the color.

**Important** the first button should always be in active mode i.e it should have the active color then if next clicked that color changes to normal and the clicked one should take the color

```
import React from 'react'

function Stddata() {
    const button_Data = [
      {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "name"
      },
      {
        "name": "Class",
        "value": "class"
      },
      {
        "name": "Age",
        "value": "age"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subjects",
        "value": "subjects"
      },
      {
        "name": "School",
        "value": "school"
      }
    ]
    return (
        <div>
            { button_Data.map(item => (
                <div key={item.value}>
            <button 
                className="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 form-control text-left"
                value={item.value}
                onClick={props.trigerOnClickEmpSideBtn}
            >{item.name}</button>
            </div>
            ))}   
        </div>
    )
}

export default Stddata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to store an active state for the button, default the state to the name of the first button.

Once you do that you can set an active className for the button which is selected.

`onClick` event of the button update the `activeButton` state.

```
const button_Data = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    value: "name"
  },
  {
    name: "Class",
    value: "class"
  },
  {
    name: "Age",
    value: "age"
  },
  {
    name: "Subjects",
    value: "subjects"
  },
  {
    name: "School",
    value: "school"
  }
];
function Stddata(props) {
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(button_Data[0].name);
  const handleClick = e => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    setActiveButton(name);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {button_Data.map(item => {
        const className = activeButton === item.name ? "active" : "";
        return (
          <div key={item.value}>
            <button
              className={`btn btn-outline-secondary mb-1 form-control text-left ${className}`}
              name={item.name}
              value={item.value}
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              {item.name}
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stddata;
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-rain-5jre7?file=/src/App.js)**

Comment: hey I have two components one  i which making button and other rendering look on triggerclick I am passing my click event, you have done this in one component only

Comment: please check the code sand box... https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-brook-en64x?file=/src/button.js

Comment: Updated link for 2 component approach. Refactored a bit of your code

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-rain-5jre7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use some state.  In your component, let's define which button is currently active.  We can use `useState` and set its starting value to 0, as you said you want to the first button to start out as active:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// inside your component
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(0)
```

And your button's `onClick` will reference the function to change the currently active button.  Within the `className`, it will check if its own index is the same as the currently active button, and set the css class accordingly:

```
{button_Data.map((item, index) => (
  <button 
    className={`btn ${activeButton === index ? 'btn-success' : null}`}  
    value={item.value} 
    onClick={ () => {setActiveButton(index)} }
  >

    {item.name}

  </button>
))}
```

### Edit: Adding [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-galileo-q9bdh)

I actually had to break off each button into its own component because each button now needs to manage its own state.  The underlying principle is the same, but each button is now its own component with its own state.

### Edit 2:

With the changes to the initial quesiton, I changed the answer.  The codesandbox also reflects these changes.  The codesandbox still uses a separate component for the button, though that's not really necessary based on the new question parameters - but the principle is the same.

Comment: hey.. this is not what I am looking for now on click of each button color is changing.. what I want is which ever button is clicked  color of that button should changed and previous once should come to normal

Comment: Ok I adjusted my answer and codesandbox.  Its doing what you're asking for.  You may need to adjust the 'hover' class for the button, as it still shows grey when hovering over an active button.  But the principle of using state and `setState` should be enough to get you going.

Comment: hey what you have done is totally oppositre to my code I cannot use that because you have made one more button component, I have a component different and it consist other stufs, can you do what my code is like'

Comment: At this point I think I've explained how to accomplish what you're trying to do....my codesandbox has the button as a separate component, true, but the answer I wrote does not.  Is that not what you're looking for already?  I think you've gotta play around with this yourself, what you're trying to do is relatively simple and is a good learning experience...

Comment: I have one component where I have all buttons and I have other components where I am rendering those buttons , But as per your code no buttons are rendering correctly

Answer (score -2):

use this component for buttons

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {View,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'

const Btn= props =>{
    if(props.touch){
        return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{...styles.boxes, ...props.style}} onPress={props.onPress}>
            {props.children}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }else{
        return (
            <View style={{...styles.boxes, ...props.style}}>
                {props.children}
            </View>
        );
    }

}
const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    boxes :{
        padding:18,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        borderRadius:20        
    }
});

export default Btn;
```

and in the page u want to have Btn  use it like this

```
<Btn style={styles.items} touch="on" onPress={props.getProductsRequest}>
               <Text  style={styles.itemTxt}> some thex</Text>
        </Btn>
```

pay attention to the touch = on

Comment: I am not using react nativve