# Is there a way to change the color/state of a button in react depending on how each state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to change the color of the button, depending on "each state". For e.g, if the state is active, the colour of the button would be red. otherwise it would be blue. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement that on react? Additionally, i would like to have different state, instead of just two. e.g. active, inactive, activating, pending etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change background color of button using react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348213/how-to-change-background-color-of-button-using-react)

Comment: also: [how to change my button color based on some condition? I want less in one color and more in another color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382538/how-to-change-my-button-color-based-on-some-condition-i-want-less-in-one-color)

Answer (score 2):

is this what you're looking for ?

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("active");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{ color: state === "active" ? "#F00" : "#00F" }}>
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good code, but you made both colors red.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice that

Comment: Hi, what if i want to make the button as a dot. Akin to a bullet point in front, do you know what GUI can I use?

Answer (score 0):

To make the bullet a dot, you can set `border-radius` into the style. Personally, I suggest you do this on a separate css file rather than directly in the attributes.

So you can have a `style.css` file

```
.App button {
    border-radius: 100%; // for a circle
}
```

And in your main js file

```
import { useState } from "react";
import './style.css'; // Or what ever path style.css is in

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("active");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{ color: state === "active" ? "#F00" : "#00F" }}>
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```